# How to play a video and audio together in android application

Tags: android, audio, video-processing

I am new to android. I want to play a audio and video together in an android application.

More specifically, In my android application, I want to play A video (without audio) with some other audio.
Do anyone have any idea how to do this?
Which android class and methods to be use to create this application?
I have found many post related to this for ios but none for android in stackoverflow.com

Thanks and looking forward for your reply.

Comment: Thanks. Do we have to use Multi-Threading to play audio and video together?

Comment: How can you start thread for audio

Comment: That's question,I am asking?   because I have heard that Multithreading is possible in Android, So i said that?  But now I realize that VideoView and MediaController are two different classes for both of them. So I guess, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you are look for is the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class.

Comment: Thanks @NINJA-  So using  MediaPlayer class, I can play both audio and video simultaneously?

Comment: I have never tried to play several streams simultaneously, but I think using different instances of the MediaPlayer class it could be possible. Here is an example how to play audio and video using MediaPlayer http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-play-video-and-audio-android

Comment: Thanks @NINJA. 
I will look at them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the VideoView and MediaController Classes together to play the video and Audio. E.g.
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.widget.MediaController;

Comment: I reckon that VideoView and MediaController don't have mute control.

Comment: @Imran, Though I have not done coding yet for this.
But I feel, If I have two instances for both of them , then How to play both together?
Using multithreading or how?

Comment: i have use both of them in a single threaded application. i develop an Android application i.e. display the video demo of my existing project. I use both of the above classes into MainActivity class and it is working for me.